# Why [a-z]{3} and [[:lower:]]{3} are different in egrep?

Tags: regex, grep

Please try

```
egrep "^[a-z]{3}$" /usr/share/dict/words

egrep "^[[:lower:]]{3}$" /usr/share/dict/words
```

The first one returns both uppercase and lowercase words.
The second one returns lowercase words only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with your locale setting. If you set `LC_ALL` to `C`, it should work as expected.

From the `egrep` manpage under Ubuntu 11.04:

> Within a bracket expression, a range expression consists of two characters separated by a  hyphen. It matches any single character that sorts between the two characters, inclusive, using the locale's collating sequence and character set.
>
> For example, in the default C locale, `[a-d]` is equivalent to `[abcd]`.  Many locales sort characters in dictionary  order, and in these locales `[a-d]` is typically not equivalent to `[abcd]`; it might be equivalent to `[aBbCcDd]`, for example. To obtain the traditional interpretation of bracket expressions, you can use the C locale by setting the `LC_ALL` environment variable to the value `C`.

You can try the commands from the following transcript to confirm this:

```
pax$ egrep "^[a-z]{3}$" /usr/share/dict/words | head -5l
AOL
Abe
Ada
Ala
Ali
pax$ LC_ALL=C egrep "^[a-z]{3}$" /usr/share/dict/words | head -5l
ace
act
add
ado
ads
```

Comment: if I separate LC_ALL=C and egrep "^[a-z]{3}$" /usr/share/dict/words | head -5l into two lines, it does not work. Why? Where can I learn about how locale works?

Comment: @jerry, you have to export it if you want it inherited by subprocesses: `export LC_ALL=C`. It's easier to use my method which changes the variable only for that one command. That way it won't affect _all_ your commands.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure? On my system (OS X Snow Leopard), both commands return exactly the same results; all 3 letter lower case words only.

```
$ egrep "^[a-z]{3}$" /usr/share/dict/words | wc -l
    1134
$ egrep "^[[:lower:]]{3}$" /usr/share/dict/words | wc -l
    1134

$ egrep "^[[:lower:]]{3}$" /usr/share/dict/words | md5
0a66d5e78cfbe6f9f66d2d90b1053972
$ egrep "^[a-z]{3}$" /usr/share/dict/words | md5
0a66d5e78cfbe6f9f66d2d90b1053972
```

What system are you using? Perhaps try `man egrep` and look for a case sensitivity option. The `egrep` that ships with OSX offers only the opposite `-i, --ignore-case ignore case distinctions`.

### Update:

I've also verified this on a CentOS linux box too:

```
$ egrep "^[a-z]{3}$" /usr/share/dict/words | wc -l
2044
$ egrep "^[[:lower:]]{3}$" /usr/share/dict/words | wc -l
2044
$ egrep "^[a-z]{3}$" /usr/share/dict/words | md5sum 
480fb21554f9f731adddb0d648157926  -
$ egrep "^[[:lower:]]{3}$" /usr/share/dict/words | md5sum 
480fb21554f9f731adddb0d648157926  -
```

### Update #2:

It appears by your comments that you may be passing the `-i` or `--ignore-case` option to `egrep`. Turn that off to get only the lower case results.

Comment: I was using ubuntu 10.10.                                            The help says -i, --ignore-case  Ignore case distinctions in both the PATTERN and the input files.  (-i is specified by POSIX.) Does it mean that grep sets -i by default?

Comment: @jerry: remove the `-i` and you'll only get the lower case results.

Comment: @jerry: When you run the commands I've included in my answer above do you get the same results for both commands?

Comment: @jerry. Ubuntu does not set `-i` by default. What the manpage is saying is that `-i` is a POSIX-originating option, not that it's _forced on_ by POSIX.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote since I _do_ consider this useful (though not necessarily right) hence +1, and not just for some mutual admiration society :-) The `-i` possibility (aliases, functions and so on) _was_ a definite possibility.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Thanks for negating the downvoter. I considered deleting the answer after seeing [yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8641090/166339) (and upvoting it), but I left it up because I thought it still might contain useful info.

Comment: @jerry: Are you sure you meant to mark my answer correct? I'm actually convinced that [@paxdiablo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8641090/166339) should be marked correct.

Comment: I am a new user... still confused about how to navigate through the site.